# How will you get 2,3, and 5 letter of first name and concat it with 2,3 letter of last name to make a new column named LETTERS OF NAME?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-modeling, data-warehouse, obiee

For example, you are given a requirement to create a column based on the following scenario:
Get letters of FirstName Column (2,3,5) CONCAT with letters of LastName column (2,3) to create a new column "LETTERS OF NAME".

P.S solution could be in SQL. I am using OBIEE if you have drag n drop solution you are welcome.

Comment: Hint:  `SUBSTR()`.

Comment: why down vote its a legit question...read the whole body if you are using OBIEE you can post the solution for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Gordon, you can use `SUBSTR()`

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME,2,2)||SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME,5,1)||SUBSTR(LAST_NAME,2,2) AS LETTERS_OF_NAME 
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```